# KUbuntu / Windows 10 dual-boot issues

Tags: ubuntu, windows, grub2, dual-boot, kubuntu

I have installed KUbuntu on my computer, along with GRUB.

I however am facing a persisting issue: whenever I boot into KUbuntu, when I shut down and boot my computer back up, I get immediately booted on KUbuntu, and I have to reboot my computer several times before it boots to GRUB. It is really frustating as I sometimes have to wait over 15 minutes to be able to log into Windows (like this morning). KUbuntu also frequently fails to boot, it shows two lines of log, or some more before and gets stuck, or when it does boot up, my mouse just wont work and I have to unplug it and plug it back in.

Is there any way I could fix this ? Thanks in advance.

- [(Small video showing what happens - I was pretty lucky by not having too much trouble this time)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZGc5rvbtock)
- [(DxDiag.txt) (I can't manage to get an English version)](https://pastebin.com/4j5ndY5g)

Comment: Are both installs in UEFI boot mode & is system set to default boot in UEFI mode? Often if mismatch, timeouts or search for other devices takes a lot of time. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ Also do you have latest firmware for your UEFI/BIOS from vendor for your model system? And if SSD latest?